# Is there a clean way of handling bad_alloc exceptions thrown inside C++ COM objects?

Tags: visual-c++, com, com-interop, directshow, new-operator

I'm working on various C++ COM DirectShow filters called from C# clients via COM interop. There's little use of C++ exceptions in the code. The main exception is operator new which can throw bad_alloc exceptions.

Is there a clean way of handling bad_alloc exceptions in a way which can be caught by the C# client?

Could a new handler throw some an SEH exception that could be caught by COM interop clients?

Or would it be better to link with the backwardly-compatible non-throwing version of new in Visual Studio libraries and check every allocation?

One tedious alternative is to write a try/catch for hundreds of COM entry points which doesn't seem worthwhile since bad_alloc exceptions are rarely recoverable.

The DirectShow base classes generally check for null returns from operator new as they seem to have been written for earlier versions of Visual C++ that didn't throw bad_alloc exceptions.

Comment: A way of making it easier to write the exception handling code is outlined in the accepted answer in this question: Code reuse in exception handling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The COM API contract requires that you not allow ANY C++ exceptions to flow across the COM API boundry.

That means you need to catch *all* C++ exceptions and turn them into HRESULTs before they leave your COM API.

You *might* be able to get away with this in some rare circumstances (if, for instance you can guarantee that the COM client and COM server were built with the same version ofthe compiler), but there are a myriad of circumstances that can mess this up (for instance the COM server lives behind a proxy/stub (which can happen if you have multiple apartments or if the server is out-of-proc), or if the COM server is being called from another language like one of the CLR languages).

In general, something like:

```
 catch (...)
 { 
     return E_FAIL;
 }
```

at the end of each of your COM APIs will go a long way to improve the robustness of your code.

Comment: Thanks, Larry. I'd probably return E_UNEXPECTED in the catch(...) case to distinguish the 'unexpected exception' mode of failure. Isn't there some danger that attempting to recover from unknown exceptions will allow a process to carry on in an unknown state possibly causing data corruption and other damage? Should client code be sensitive to this possibility?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to catch the exception and return E_OUTOFMEMORY.  Only do this for large allocations, there's little point in trying to stumble on when small ones fail.  Nothing good ever happens after the program has consumed 2 gigabytes of virtual memory, you might as well let it die.  Large allocations are likely to fail due to address space fragmentation, there can still be lots of unused space left.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, wrap all methods into big `try-catch`:

```
#define BEGIN_COM_METHOD try {

#define END_COM_METHOD \
} catch( const std::bad_alloc& ) {\
     return E_OUTOFMEMORY;\
} catch( ... ) {\
     return E_FAIL;\
}\
return S_OK;

HRESULT YourComClass::SomeMethod()
{
    BEGIN_COM_METHOD
       DoUsefulStuff();
    END_COM_METHOD
}
```

Using this you no longer propagate exceptions through the COM boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I can see why C++ exceptions can't reliably pass a COM boundary. What does the COM contract have to say about structured exceptions flowing across a COM boundary though?

How about the following technique which turns operator new failures into structured exceptions? Or are there good reasons why this is a bad idea?

```
void __cdecl OutOfMemoryHandler()
{
    RaiseException(STATUS_NO_MEMORY, 0, 0, NULL);
}

std::set_new_handler(OutOfMemoryHandler);
```

I notice that ATL can do a similar trick in AtlThrow of handling E_OUTOFMEMORY HRESULT by raising STATUS_NO_MEMORY structured exceptions though the behaviour depends on the preprocessor symbols defined.

In native code this technique would also suggest that the /EHa compiler option heeds to set so that stack unwinding happens and destructors get called for structured exceptions. I can see this would cause a performance hit if I were using a lot of try/catch clauses but in the current context I'm using no try/catch clauses at all. Would I still get a performance hit from using /EHa?

Structure exception handling compiler settings may be a good idea in any case. Another stack overflow poster describes a nasty bug where a C++ object wrapped critical section (commonly used in the DirectShow base classes) failed to unlock when a structured exception was raised in a called module. The compiler settings were set for C++ exception handling only and the object wrapping the critical section did not get destroyed when the structured exception was raised and deadlock happened later on.

Comment: No, you should not allow any exceptions to pass through COM boundary, period.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110120-00/?p=11713

Comment: Really interesting blog post from Raymond Chen, thanks for posting